# DispatcherTimer in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: development

My dispatcher timer is not calling on timer_tick event.
it's my code:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += timer_tick();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,10);
timer.Start();

timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...}
```

Plz, help me!

Comment: Closed at request of OP

Answer (score 1):

I'm found solution of my problem.  PageLoad method exits prior to when the first DispatcherTimer event could ever occur.

As soon as Main finishes, the process will shut down, as there are no other foreground threads.

That being said, DispatcherTimer really only makes sense in a use case where you have a Dispatcher, such as a WPF or Silverlight application. Therefore, I'm should consider using the Timer class.

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
_timer.Interval = 5000;
_timer.Elapsed  += _timer_Tick;
_timer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your eventhandler binding is incorrect, correct is:

> timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);

It is best to hit TAB after typing += and Visual Studio will magically create the event handler code for you.

Comment: Jussi Palo,
I know about TAB :) simply i'm using Resharper, and it's suggested more universal subscribe to events. But with timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick); my dispatcher also timer is not calling on timer_tick event. I don't know why :(((